# How is JP calculated at the end of battle?

Tags: bravely-default

What determines how much JP you earn at the end of each battle? One thing I can determine is that each enemy has a set number that you are awarded, but how can you increase this?

In a test of fighting the same enemy, I have been rewarded with 15, 16, 18 and 22 JP at the end of a battle.

Comment: As far as I know one way is to earn the JP bonus (Unscathed) and its subsequent chains. But I'm not sure if there aren't any more ways like using the job skills.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each enemy killed is worth a certain amount of JP. If you fight a battle without taking damage, you earn an "Unscathed" bonus, which is worth an additional 10% JP. If you are Unscathed in 9 more subsequent battles, the JP bonus increases to 20%. Another 10 Unscathed battles will get you a 50% JP bonus.

Comment: Note that the Freelancer gains a support ability at rank 10 called JP Up, which further increases JP gain by 20%.